# Windows Store Apps: ScrollViewer delay in data binding?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a **LayoutAwarePage** where its layout is a **ScrollViewer** that wraps some controls (Text boxes, text blocks, ...), these controls are bound to properties in the view model.

My problem is that when I load some save values in the **LoadState** event of the page (saved text box values and so on), the values are retrieved correctly but not displayed in the controls, something like this

```
    protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
    {
    if(pageState!=null)
    {
    if(pageState.ContainsKey(STATE_TEXT))
    {
//set the text of the text box
    txtUserName.Text=pageState[STATE_TEXT].ToString();
    }
    }
    }
```

When I do the above, the text box text is blank.

However, I found that when I remove the scrollviewer, it works just fine.

Also if I set the text if the txtUserName to any value in the Loaded event of the scrollviewer, the text appears normally in the text box.

what can be wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

if you use a DataContext to assign properties, maybe that's what's overriding the changes you make in the LoadState-Method.

Maybe you could share the relevant XAML, the whole (relevant) parts of the LoadState and the parts of your ViewModel that are relevant for this (ctor e.g.)

greetings